# Create a Specific JSON file from csv in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, csv

I have no experience with PowerShell and I was asked to create this script as a favor for a friend of mine. The script is supposed to read a csv file (These files have different columns except for time and host, which are common among all files), and output its content into a JSON file of the following format:

CSV file contains columns:

host| message | time | severity | source |

```
{
"time": 1437522387,
"host": "dataserver992.example.com",
"event": { 
    "message": "Something happened",
    "severity": "INFO",
    "source": "testapp"
    #...All columns except for time and host should be under "event"
    }
}
```

*The only guaranteed columns are time and host. All other column headers vary from file to file.

This is part of what I have so far:

```
$csvFile = Import-Csv $filePath


function jsonConverter($file)
{    
    #Currently not in use
    $eventString = $file| select * -ExcludeProperty time, host 


    $file | Foreach-Object {
        Write-Host '{'
        Write-Host '"host":"'$_.host'",'
        Write-Host '"time":"'$_.time'",'

        Write-Host '"event":{'

        #TODO: Put all other columns (key, values) under event - Except for 
        time and host

        Write-Host '}'
    }    
}

jsonConverter($csvFile)
```

Any ideas of how I could extract only the remaining columns, row by row, outputting its content to a key, value JSON format like the example above?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Provided your csv looks like this:

```
"host","message","time","severity","source"
"dataserver992.example.com","Something happened","1437522387","INFO","testapp"
```

this script:

```
$filepath = '.\input.csv'
$csvData = Import-Csv $filePath

$NewCsvData  = foreach($Row in $csvData){
   [PSCustomObject]@{
       time  =  $Row.time
       host  =  $Row.host
       event = ($Row| Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty time,host)
   }
}

$NewCsvData | ConvertTo-Json
```

will output this Json:

```
{
    "time":  "1437522387",
    "host":  "dataserver992.example.com",
    "event":  {
                  "message":  "Something happened",
                  "severity":  "INFO",
                  "source":  "testapp"
              }
}
```

Comment: I first didn't remember that the parameter `-ExcludeProperty` requires the parameter `-Property` to also be present.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If your powershell version is 3.0 or higher (it should):

```
Import-CSV $filepath | ConvertTo-JSON
```

Done!

Comment: Hey, that doesn't work because "event" is not actually a column in the csv file. "event" is like a key where I have to put all columns except for host and time. This is a customized JSON file. See example above.

Comment: Just baked something like @LotPings. But slightly less distinguished. So use his code ;-)